# Initialize KeyValuePairs from array, from dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

According to the doc, [KeyValuePairs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyvaluepairs) is lightweight collection of key-value pairs. Much like an ordered [Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary). KeyValuePairs has similar [initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyvaluepairs/3127882-init) to init from literal. But unlike it's unordered counterpart it lacks inits from sequences of key-value tuples. Can we add more inits, to obtain KeyValuePairs from Sequences, Collections or Dictionary or at least from array of tuples?

For example, I need a sorted version of such a Dictionary

```
static var allRegionIsoCodesWithNames: Dictionary<String, String> {
    get {
        return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: Locale.isoRegionCodes.map({ ($0, String.emojiFlag(for: $0)!  + LWUserDefaults.locale.localizedString(forRegionCode: $0)!) }).sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 }))
    }
}
/* A useless code since ordering is not applyed */
```

I need this one to work

```
static var allRegionIsoCodesWithNamesKeyVal: KeyValuePairs<String, String>? {
    get {
        return Array(Locale.isoRegionCodes.map({ ($0, String.emojiFlag(for: $0)!  + LWUserDefaults.locale.localizedString(forRegionCode: $0)!) }).sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 }))
    }
}
/* Cannot convert return expression of type '[(String, String)]' to return type 'KeyValuePairs<String, String>?' */
```

In order to reproduce here is the String.emojiFlag (for reference):

```
extension String {
    static func emojiFlag(for countryCode: String) -> String? {
        func isLowercaseASCIIEnglishLetterScalar(_ scalar: Unicode.Scalar) -> Bool {
            return scalar.value >= Unicode.Scalar("a").value && scalar.value <= Unicode.Scalar("z").value
        }

        func regionalIndicatorSymbol(for scalar: Unicode.Scalar) -> Unicode.Scalar {
            precondition(isLowercaseASCIIEnglishLetterScalar(scalar))
            return Unicode.Scalar(scalar.value + (0x1F1E6 - 0x61))!
        }

        let lowercasedCode = countryCode.lowercased()
        guard lowercasedCode.unicodeScalars.allSatisfy(isLowercaseASCIIEnglishLetterScalar) else {return nil }

        let indicatorSymbols = lowercasedCode.unicodeScalars.map({ regionalIndicatorSymbol(for: $0) })
        return String(indicatorSymbols.map({ Character($0) }))
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you just want to return `[(String, String)]` in `allRegionIsoCodesWithNamesKeyVal` and you'd have what you're describing. Why do you need KeyValuePairs?

Comment: Mostly because KeyValuePairs is standard library thing and it looks like it is designated to be used where you need a sorted Dictionary, @Rob. We can always fallback to an Array, but maybe there is a better way. Besides a proper type gives a clue for the reader of code.

Comment: It really isn't, though. It used to be named `DictionaryLiteral` and was renamed because it is neither a Dictionary nor a literal. https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0214-DictionaryLiteral.md  It was almost deprecated, but occasionally it's useful (specifically to keep track of order when passing values to a function). It is not an ordered dictionary. It's just a wrapper around `[(String, String)]`, but it doesn't have subscripting (the keys don't even have to be Equatable). I would use `[(String, String)]` here.

Comment: It rarely makes sense as a return type; it's valuable to work around current Swift extension limitations as a parameter type.

Comment: Agree with both comments, @Rob. It just seemed to me it would be useful to have an ordered version of Dictionary in standard library. 
KeyValuePairs seemed to be close.